# Don't understand what this error means: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I'm new to python and struggling to understand what this error means:
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

here is the full code:

```
import openpyxl, pprint,os
os.chdir('C:\Users\Shend_000\Documents\Py CWD')
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Population by Census Tract')
countyData={}
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row()):
    state=sheet['B'+str(row)].value
    county=sheet['C'+str(row)].value
    pop=sheet['D'+str(row)].value
    countyData.setdefault(state,{})
    countyData[state].setdefault(county,{'tracts':0, 'pop':0})
    countyData[state][county]['tracts']+=1
    countyData[state][county]['pop']+=int(pop)
resultFile=open('census2010.py','w')
resultFile.write('allData= '+pprint.pformat(countyData))
resultFile.close()
print 'Done.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change this:

```
for row in range(2,sheet.max_row):
```

`sheet.max_row` returns `int` and you can't call `int`.